# How to get node-sass to not create a .css version of the @imported .scss file that changed, but only the main.css which imports it

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have a simply HTML/SCSS website.

In my /scss directory I have one file `main.scss` which imports 4 other .scss files.

I start the website with `npm start` which **correctly parses all the .scss files into only one `css/main.css` file** and then watches for changes in all the .scss files:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node-sass -r scss/main.scss -o css &&  node-sass --watch scss -o css"
}
```

The problem is, when I change any of the imported `.scss` files, it not only parses and recreates `css/main.css` (which is all I need for my HTML page), but it also parses the imported file into the `css` directory, which I don't need.

Is there a way to tell node-sass that, when it sees a change in an imported `.scss` file, to only create the `css/main.css` file and not the .css version of the .scss file that changed?

Comment: You need to rename your other sass files to partials `e.g: other1.scss becomes _other1.scss` [Read about partials here](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4)

Comment: Thanks, that worked in my case. The documentation at the link you posted states "Sass partials are used with the @use rule," which however doesn't work. Confusing. But the @import command seems to work fine for partials with a preceding underscore and only creates `main.css`. Nice.

Comment: `@use` is a new way of loading styles and it has a lot of benifits [Read Here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use), I suggest you if possible start using `@use` since `@import` is deprecated and will be removed completely, Here is a [good video on this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0&ab_channel=KevinPowell) to start with.

Comment: Excellent, that's an informative video. Thanks for the orientation on this.